# python asynchronous map function that apply a function to every element of a list

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have a list of elements in python that I want to apply an API call to. The API involves web requests and I want to apply it synchronously. Since it is a third party API I can't really modify the code inside as well. I want to have something like this:

```
from API import get_user_handle
arr = [1234, 2345, 6789] # list of user id
new_arr = async_foreach(arr, get_user_handle)
print(new_arr) # e.g. ['Tom', 'Amy', 'Jerry']
```

This would be easy in nodejs by using the array map function. How do I build something similar in python?

Comment: Is `get_user_handle` a coroutine created using the `async def` signature or a regular synchronous function? If a regular function, are you wanting to run it in separate threads or perhaps separate processes?

Comment: It is a regular function. That makes sense. How would I implement it? I am not very familiar with multithreading

Comment: If one of the three answers answered your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concurrent.futures`, I suggest using threads in this case, if you are IO bound:

```
import concurrent.futures

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    new_arr = executor.map(get_user_handle, arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a thread or process pool. For example

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from API import get_user_handle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [1234, 2345, 6789] # list of user id
    # guess some reasonable subprocess pool size. This one creates
    # 2 processes per cpu assuming there is I/O wait time. Needs
    # tweeking to environment.
    count = min(len(arr), mp.cpu_count() * 2)
    with mp.Pool(count) as pool:
        new_arr = pool.map(get_user_handle, arr)
    print(new_arr) # e.g. ['Tom', 'Amy', 'Jerry']
```

Thread pools are faster to launch and to pass data in and out. But Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) only lets a single thread run at a time. If an operation is mostly I/O bound, it is a good choice.

If the data sent to/from the parallelized is small compared to the CPU load of the function being run, a process pool makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this can be done using the `map` function in Python. Here's an example:

```py
import requests

def check_site_up(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    return res.status_code

sites_to_check = ["https://google.com", "https://youtube.com", "https://yahoo.com"]

results = list(map(check_site_up, sites_to_check))

print(results)

>>> [200, 200, 200]
```

The `map` function is **not** asynchronous though, so if you're trying to make requests asynchronously, you would likely need to wrap it in an async function, i.e.

```py
from asyncstdlib.builtins import map as amap
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def anext(ait):
    return await ait.__anext__()

async def check_site_up(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            page = await resp.text()
            status = resp.status
            return status


async def main():
    sites_to_check = ["https://google.com", "https://youtube.com", "https://yahoo.com"]
    results = amap(check_site_up, sites_to_check)
    status_results = list()
    async for res in results:
        status_results.append(res)
    return status_results

status_codes = asyncio.run(main())

print(status_codes)

>>> [200,200,200]
```